# How avoiding circle tag during the build in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I have hook in my GitHub to Jenkins. every time I push or PR, it trigger the build/deploy.

During the build I want to tag the source with the version number.

The problem is I run `git tag ..`, and then I need to push the change to the repo, which trigger another build.

I also can't use just `git push origin --tags` because I change the version in `package.json`, and I need to push it to my repo.

How solving this case? maybe to do push but tell github to ignore the webhook at this time? if so, how?